# VBA: get data having hyphen in the begining

Tags: excel, vba

When I enter data in excel cell with prefixing hyphen like " 'Data ",it does not get you hyphen when you fetch it in vba, but it`ll be visible in formula bar. How to handle this? I can not change the data. How to get the data displayed in formula bar?

I`m using Range.value to get data.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you use in VBA to get the data? `Range.Value` or `Range.Text` or `Range.Formula`?

Comment: I`m using Range.value to get data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to check for the prefix with `Range(myRange).PrefixCharacter` and then handle it.